# Coqide 8.5: No syntax highlighting on Linux

Tags: linux, syntax-highlighting, nix, coqide

I installed Coqide 8.5 w/ `nix`. Unfortunately, the text is blakc in all panels; there's no syntax highlighting of any kind (otherwise, 8.5 seems a big improvement over 8.4, which I've installed as well). I also get the following:

```
(coqide:17272): GtkSourceView-WARNING **: Unknown parent scheme 'classic' in scheme 'coq_style'

(coqide:17272): GtkSourceView-WARNING **: Failed to load '/nix/store/2sxcqfc4q3ls4g2q13n1zwfhnydvgq-coq-8.5pl1/share/coq/coq.lang': could not find the RelaxNG schema file
```

The output of `cat ~/.nix-profile/share/coq/coq_style.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<style-scheme id="coq_style" _name="Coq highlighting based on Ssr manual"
          parent-scheme="classic" version="1.0">
<author>The Coq Dev Team</author>
<_description>Coq/Ssreflect color scheme for the vernacular language</_description>

<style name="coq:comment" foreground="#brown"/>
<style name="coq:coqdoc" foreground="#brown" italic="true"/>
<style name="coq:vernac-keyword" bold="true" foreground="#dark violet"/>
<style name="coq:gallina-keyword" bold="true" foreground="#orange red"/>
<style name="coq:identifier" foreground="#navy"/>
<style name="coq:constr-keyword" foreground="#dark green"/>
<style name="coq:constr-sort" foreground="#008080"/>

<style name="coq-ssreflect:comment" foreground="#b22222"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:coqdoc" foreground="#b22222" italic="true"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:vernac-keyword" bold="true" foreground="#a021f0"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:gallina-keyword" bold="true" foreground="#a021f0"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:identifier" bold="true" foreground="#0000ff"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:constr-keyword" foreground="#228b22"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:constr-sort" foreground="#228b22"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:tactic" foreground="#101092"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:endtactic" foreground="#ff3f3f"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:iterator" foreground="#be6ad4"/>
<style name="coq-ssreflect:string" foreground="#8b2252"/>
</style-scheme>
```

Given the first warning, I guess there should be something else instead of `"classic"` but what

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have `libgtksourceview3.0-common` installed but CoqIDE depends on `libgtksourceview2.0-common`. Installing the latter fixed it

Comment: Could you explicit how you installed these packages? Using `nix` or another package manager? Which command did you use?

Comment: 3.0 came installed w/ my distro (Linux Light, a spinoff of Ubuntu). I don't remember about 2.0 but `~/.nix-profile/share` shows only `~coq` and `~nix`, so 2.0 was installed w/ synaptic

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same issue with `coqide` installed via `nix` (in the `coq-8.6` package).

Here's a script that installs symlinks to some files in your homedir to work around several warning messages:

```sh
## Find the nix-installed version of the GTK SourceView 2.0 library
sourceview="$(nix-env -q coq --no-name --out-path |
    xargs nix-store -q --references |
    grep -- -gtksourceview-)"

## Link files into the correct hierarchical folders in your home dir:
share=share/gtksourceview-2.0
for file in language-specs/language2.rng \
    language-specs/def.lang \
    styles/classic.xml
do
    target="$HOME/.local/$share/$file"
    mkdir -vp "$(dirname "$target")"
    ln -vfns "$sourceview/$share/$file" "$target"
done
```

This fixes the following `GtkSourceView-WARNING`s:

```config
## fixed by language-specs/language2.rng
Failed to load '.../share/coq/coq.lang': could not find the RelaxNG schema file

## fixed by language-specs/def.lang
in file .../share/coq/coq.lang: style 'def:comment' not defined
Failed to load '.../share/coq/coq.lang': unable to resolve language 'def'

## fixed by styles/classic.xml
Unknown parent scheme 'classic' in scheme 'coq_style'
```

I'll likely try to fix the `coq` derivation at some point to avoid needing this workaround.  I suspect either or both of the following would need to be done:

- Fix how `coq` sets up the GTK SourceView search paths (since it includes the language definition)
- Fix how `gnome2.gtksourceview` exports its search path(s) for other programs to use

Comment: Very nice! BTW this hinted me towards another (temporary) solution which is just: `nix-env -iA nixos.gnome2.gtksourceview` since this brings the `share/` folder of this package somewhere that CoqIDE can find.