# No syntax highlighting in CoqIde

Tags: syntax-highlighting, coq, coqide

I use OpenSuse Leap, and build Coq-8.5 from sources. But there is no syntax coloring in coqide and in preferences I can't choose Language:
[image: preferences]

In console output I have only:

```
(coqide:30790): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GtkWindow:allow-grow is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.

(coqide:30790): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: The property GtkWindow:allow-shrink is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version.
Theme directory actions/48 of theme breeze has no size field

Theme directory categories/16 of theme breeze has no size field

Theme directory categories/22 of theme breeze has no size field

Theme directory categories/48 of theme breeze has no size field

Theme directory devices/48 of theme breeze has no size field

Theme directory  of theme oxygen has no size field
```

All libriaries like `libgtksourceview` I've installed.

Comment: In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901837/coqide-8-5-no-syntax-highlighting-on-linux, the problem was the version of gtksourceview. Did you use the good one ?

Comment: I install `libgtksourceview3.0` and `libgtksourceview2.0`